# Suggestion on how to implement address search on google maps on Android similar to google maps app?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, android-maps-v2

I am trying to implement a feature in my app that has these main rquirements:

1. Show location on google map
2. Search for address and show location around that
3. Autocomplete address

I want to make the UI and behavior similar to google maps app.

If somebody can provide suggestion on best way to implement the search box? Seems like its needs to be custom made.

I am using https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel to show marker details

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a `AutocompleteTextView` for your search bar. You can visit [this Google Maps Autocomplete tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/) for detailed implementation.